# Error with mle2: 3 arguments passed to '('

Tags: r, mle

I'm trying to estimate parameters for a model, according to a formula:

```
 mat_est <- formula(m_rate ~ (((0.02139*TempK/298)*
    exp(A_m*(1/198-1/TempK)))/
    (1+exp(A_l*(1/295.05-1/TempK))+
    exp(A_h*(1/312-1/TempK)))))
mat_fit <- mle2(mat_est, 
     start= list(A_m=6387, A_l= -56734,  A_h=28149),
     data= BF006_fam)
```

the data has about 10 measurements for m_rate for 4 temperatures (`TempK`)
starting values were obtained from past experiments

When I tried running the code, I ran into the following error:

> Error in (c(0.0289855072463768, 0.0273972602739726, 0.0273972602739726,  :
> 3 arguments passed to '(' which requires 1

Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: Hi there, have you tried start=list(c()) rather than start=list())

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be running `nls()` instead of `bbmle::mle2`. `mle2` is expecting you to specify a response distribution, e.g. `y~dpois(x,lambda=L)`. Here's a simple example that generates your error:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:3,y=2:4)
bbmle::mle2(y~(a*x), start=list(a=1), data=d)
```

> Error in (2:4) : 3 arguments passed to '(' which requires 1

If you use `nls()` instead, it works

```
nls(y~(a*x), start=list(a=1), data=d)
```

Note that fitting a three-parameter nonlinear model to data collected at only 4 distinct temperature values will be extremely challenging unless you have very good starting values and/or very clean data.